# akashic records and Hinduism

Tags: vedas, krishna, puranas, brahma, rishi

Akashic Records are defined by some hindus and theosophists as  a compendium of thoughts, events, and emotions  encoded in a non-physical plane of existence known as the astral plane.

Its been believed that , nothing actually lost in the world.Each thought , event , all books are perfectly recorded in this infinite medium. Only few people who are capable of reading it can access it.

One recent example is , pandit subbaraya shastri , who accessed portions of vaimanika shastra( written by sage Bharadvaja) , which was supposed to be lost.But I couldn't find any references or quotes of its existence in any of books I have read.

Does any one aware of explicit references of such things in any hindu scriptures?

Comment: Yes ofcourse in Hinduism Chitragupta and Yamaraja keep records of every action done by every jiva on Earth so that they can be accounted. This can be viewed as akashic records. All the best

Comment: I heard , those records are typically kept inside the jeevatma itself. Chitragupta would simply look into those records in order to retrieve those data.

Comment: Offcourse whatever stored in jeevatma can be part of akashic records , but akashic records has much more than that.

Comment: oh ok. where did you hear it? That records are kept inside jeevatma sir? thank you :)

Comment: Theosophy is not Hinduism. Hinduism is not Theosophy. There is no reference to any 'akashic records' in the Upanishads, the Brahma-Sutras, or the Bhagavad Gita. It may be in some Purana. There is no need for 'recording' - everything is known by Saguna Brahman and perfected souls as there is no past, present, or future for them.

Comment: "Our consciousness has records of all that is happening, what we call akashic records. 
Now, in this place, there are one thousand television channels right here. If you take a very powerful television channel and put a booster you can get all the channels of the world right now in this place.
That means the empty space which we think is empty is not empty. It has records of all that is going on, of all that has happened in the past and all that will happen in the future, now in this moment. 
It is a very fascinating aspect of consciousness." - Sri Sri Ravi Shankar

Comment: Have heard this many times, existence of akashic records, and one consequence of this is that all the lost shastras and religious texts could be recovered (by people at a higher level of understanding.) Maybe nothing is really “lost” in that sense, just whoever says that isn’t at a high enough level to access it, it’s just not available to them. But it isn’t lost, due to akashic records.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Akashic records" was first used by Theosophists in the 1800s. The word itself was created from the Sanskrit "akasha", but that in and of itself does not mean that it's origin lies in any Sanskrit literature.

Philosophically it is entirely reasonable to assume that the thoughts of every being are imprinted onto the fabric of our Universe in the realm of the citta. The same thing happens to our subtle body as the four functions of the mind (manas, citta, ahankara and buddhi) interact to create what we perceive as consciousness. So, universally speaking, the same must happen.

But this does not mean that there are "keepers" of these records and all of the other things that go along with it. Those assumptions are not stipulated in any shastra, so they are merely speculations. Of course one could access the thoughts of others through this medium, but one must be careful to simply equate this faculty with the "Akashic records".

An important point to mention is that the Upanishads are "heard" (sruti) by those who are qualified (and subsequently passed on). But this "sound" is part of the fabric of the Universe itself, and isn't due to the thoughts of (deceased) living entities.

As for your example...

"One recent example is , pandit subbaraya shastri , who accessed portions of vaimanika shastra( written by sage Bharadvaja) "

The argument can be made that this knowledge was "encoded" within the very Universe at its creation, or subsequently by a Deva, and then accessed by someone who was qualified. Another possibility is that it was received directly from another living entity. No need for (man made) Akashic records.

A clear distinction between "encoded into the fabric of the Universe" and "recorded thoughts of living entities" must thus be made. As all of us will hopefully attest, many of the thoughts of living entities are quite useless.

One could therefore make another strong argument that "everything" isn't stored, as this would result in a lot of "noise" which would drown out the useful information or higher knowledge.

The point was made that all actions are recorded by Yamaraja. Obviously someone has to take care of the administrative aspect of karma. Only novice (and mostly Western) students of Hinduism are so naive as to think that matter moves itself. But does that have anything to do with the Akashic records? In truth, not at all.

So go back to what the Akashic records are proposed to be, "records of the past and future of human thought and action".

I've given a long reply to your question, because I believe the this is yet another case of modern speculation being equated with the knowledge received from the ancients. It's a dangerous game to play.